# Mongo DB, delete redundant data, how to delete duplicate unique index from the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a collection which has redundant data.

**Example Data:**

```
{
    unique_index : "1"
    other_field : "whatever1"
},
{
    unique_index : "2"
    other_field : "whatever2"
},
{
    unique_index : "1"
    other_field : "whatever1"
}
```

I ran the query: (I have to use `allowDiskUse:true` because there is lot of data)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: "$unique_index", 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        } 
    }, 
    { $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } }
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

I get this output: (for example)

```
{ "_id" : "1", "count" : 2 }
.
.
```

Now the problem is that I want to keep only one data. I want to delete all redundant data. Please note that its lot of data, like more than 100,000 records or something. I am searching for fast and easy solution (in mongodb or RoR because I am using Ruby on Rails), if any one can help, would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which one is redundant, when documents differ. I.e. same `unique_index` but different `other_field`?

Comment: @AlexBlex other_field can never be different, its same data, I know this because I its inserted by me (code to insert was written by me), you can safely assume that its 100% redundant

Comment: Well, the reason I asked, is that documents have at least 1 unique field, `_id` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about `_id`, the simplest way is to select distinct documents into new collection, and then rename it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: "$unique_index", 
        other_field: {$first: "$other_field"}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        unique_index: "$_id",
        other_field:1
    }},
    {$out: "new_collection"}
]);

db.new_collection.renameCollection("collection", true);
```

Please bear in mind, you will need to restore all indexes. Also `renameCollection` is not working on sharded colelctions.

Comment: Hey few doubts, thanks for the answer: I just got one mongo DB instance, only one , only primary, I just type mongo  in command line and it opens, so I can do renameCollection there right? And Can you please use allowDiskUse as well because that is needed else memory gets exceeded and unique index is not _id, _id is different and unique_index is different, just to let you know, i hope your query is safe to run I just want to be sure.. and it has many other fields as well, I need to project them all? And before renaming New_C to C, I should delete C ?